# How to update the gui while the program is running in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Essentially I just want to update the grid on the GUI while the Tkinter program is running, the changes I want to make while the program is running are under the return true part in the function but I can't find how to do this.

```
import random
from tkinter import *

def input_validation(coordinates, user_input):
    if coordinates [0] <0 or coordinates [1] <0 or coordinates [0] >2 or coordinates [1] >2:
        pass
    elif (int(user_input) == int(frame.grid_slaves(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])[0]['text'])):
        return True

    Label (frame, text = frame.grid_slaves(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])[0]['text']
           ).grid(row= previous_coordinates[0], column= previous_coordinates[1])
    Label (frame, text = "").grid(row= coordinates[0], column= coordinates[1])

def button_click():
    if (input_validation(coordinates_up, number_input.get()) == True):
        pass
    elif(input_validation(coordinates_left, number_input.get()) == True):
        pass
    elif(input_validation(coordinates_right, number_input.get()) == True):
        pass
    elif(input_validation(coordinates_down, number_input.get()) == True):
        pass
    else:
        print("hello")
        text_display.configure(text="Please input a number that is surrounding the empty space")

puzzle  = Tk()
puzzle.title("Eight Puzzle")
frame = Frame(puzzle)
space_coordinates = [2,2]

frame.pack()

number_input= Entry(frame, width= 20)
number_input.grid(row = 5, column =7)

button = Button(frame, text="Enter", command = button_click)
button.grid(row = 6, column = 7)
number = 8

text_display = Label(frame, text="Input the number you want to move into the empty space \n *make sure the number is next to the empty space*", fg="red")
text_display.grid(row = 3, column = 7)

for i in range (0,3):
    for a in range (0,3):
        if number == 0:
            Label (frame, text = " ").grid(row=i, column=a)
        else:
            Label (frame, text = number).grid(row=i, column=a)
        number= number -1

previous_coordinates = []
previous_coordinates.append(space_coordinates[0])
previous_coordinates.append(space_coordinates[1])

coordinates_up = [previous_coordinates[0], previous_coordinates[1]-1]
coordinates_left = [previous_coordinates[0]-1, previous_coordinates[1]]
coordinates_right = [previous_coordinates[0]+1, previous_coordinates[1]]
coordinates_down = [previous_coordinates[0],previous_coordinates[1]+1]
```

Comment: Are you looking for `puzzle.mainloop()`? Try putting it at the end of your code

Comment: @TheLizzard would that help with updating the GUI at the specified part ?

Comment: It will tell tkinter that it needs to go in its mainloop which is basically a `while True` loop updates the GUI until the window is closed

Answer (score 1):

You will need `puzzle.mainloop()` at the end of your `tkinter` program. Also, if you want to update the window mid-function, you can use: `window.update()`

Comment: Replace `window` with the name of your window (in your case, `puzzle.update()`)